# datepicker using name instead of id, but using myname[]

Tags: datepicker

I have a form with multiple grouped fields, apart from other text fields there is a 'start' and 'end' date I wish to use the datepicker on.

It only works on the first group.  How can I get datepicker to work on each grouped set of fields without conflicting with the other groups?

```
        $(function() {
    <!--$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fi']);-->
        $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    regional: "fi",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        }
        });
    });


            $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".addMore").click(function(){     var fieldHTML = '<div class="eventGroup">'+$(".eventGroupCopy").html()+'</div>';    $('body').find('.eventGroup:last').after(fieldHTML);    });//add more fields group
            $("body").on("click",".remove",function(){  $(this).parents(".eventGroup").remove();    });//remove fields group
        });


            <form method="post" action="editSpecialDatePrices.php">


        <?php
//          if ($getEventDetails->num_rows == 0) {
//              foreach($getEventDetails as $eventDetail) {
                ?>
                <div class="eventGroup">
                    <input type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter name" value="<?php //if($_POST[) {  } else {  } ?>"><br>
                    <input type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price"><br>
                    <input type="text" id="from" name="eventStart[]" placeholder="Enter Start Date"><br>
                    <input type="text" id="to" name="eventEnd[]" placeholder="Enter End Date"><br>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a>
                </div>
                <?php
//              }
//          }
        ?>
        <div class="eventGroup" style="display: none;"></div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="addMore">Add more</a>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
        </form>
        <!-- copy of input fields group -->
        <div class="eventGroupCopy" style="display: none;">
            <input type="text" name="eventName[]" placeholder="Enter Event Name"><br>
            <input type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="Enter Price"><br>
                    <input type="text" id="from" name="eventStart[]" placeholder="Enter Start Date"><br>
                    <input type="text" id="to" name="eventEnd[]" placeholder="Enter End Date"><br>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove">Remove</a><br><br>
        </div>
```